# Choose or force EngineeringForm[] exponent multiple

Tags: output-formatting

Does anyone know of a way to make `EngineeringForm[...]` use a specific multiple of three for the power.

E.g. so $1\times10^9$ will be represented as $1000\times10^6$ if the user always wanted the result output as $10^6$.

EDIT: Just for clarity, two users have suggested `EngineeringForm[x, ExponentStep -> n]` however this is quite limited. For example a number is output as $2.1\times10^{-13}$ and I want it in the form of $10^{-12}$ then the suggested function will not work as the step size cannot take a lower value that $1$.

Comment: It likely does not do all you want and you may need to write a custom module to do all that you want, but try: EngineeringForm[1. 10^9,10, ExponentStep -> 6]. Notice the real format as opposed to symbolic form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NumberForm[1.23456789*10^15, 10, ExponentFunction -> (6 &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

produces the desired result.

Comment: User @Moo has already made this suggestion in a comment. It lacks versatility however. For example if the number is output as $10^{-13}$ the function you suggest will not work if I want it in the form of $10^{-12}$.

Comment: @QuantumPenguin I updated after getting access to my PC

Comment: LaVinge Perfect.